# Flink shows a job isrunning in UI but the job actually not working

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

This is regarding a flink job which has a simple source to fetch data from a url and then filter the data then collects data in a process function for some time (keyBy) and at last process on collected data in a map. Due to some reasons the job stops functioning after some days even though the flink UI is showing it as running. Is there any way to know why there is such a behavious, also is there any way i can know if a job has actually stopped even though UI showing it as running.

P.S. How do i know the job has stopped?? Ans : It doesn't perform the task it was performing.
I checked the logs but it didn't help me much understanding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the job manager and task manager(s) are still running, since at least the heartbeat messages are being delivered.

There are a number of metrics that might shed some light on what is happening:

If the job is using event time, perhaps an idle source is causing the watermarks to no longer advance. You should be able to see this in the metrics by looking at the numRecordsOutPerSecond from the source instances, and by looking at the current watermark.

If you are reading from Kafka (or Kinesis), look at records-lag-max (or millisBehindLatest).

If you have checkpoints enabled, look to see if they are still succeeding.